# If I am dead there is no death; What am I?

Tags: riddle

> If I am dead there is no death,
>   But nor would life exist,
>   No universe would ever be,
>   No water, earth, or stone.
>
> No riddle ever spoke or read,
>   My binding spell escapes,
>   Unconquered by the darkness yet,
>   Though light escapes my fate.
>
> I appear in the fire’s flames,
>   Lurk in the dragon’s den,
>   The number of a man acclaimed,
>   Within me there resides.

I am really not sure if this riddle is too easy or too hard, I'll leave that to you to decide.

Minor hint:

> I am not mentioned in the poem.

Now that is has been solved, something which went unnoticed (Spoiler!):

> The answer also appears in the last word of every line.

Comment: Beautiful not-so-rhyming riddle! Congratulations on your very first post on the **Puzzling.SE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)**! :D

Comment: It's very impressive indeed that the whole puzzle is in near-perfect [iambic heptameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteener_(poetry))! (Oh, if only it were possible to substitute "The dark" for "Darkness"..)

Comment: Thanks @user477343! I've had the idea for this riddle for a *long* time, but just never got round to it. I just decided to bash it together on Saturday afternoon.

Comment: @Bass maybe with a bit of work I could fix that : )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, you could conceivably be

> the letter **e**.

That would figure, since

> every word mentioned in the poem as being affected contains the letter e:
>
>  If I am dead there is no d**e**ath,
>  But nor would lif**e** exist,
>  No univ**e**rs**e** would ever be,
>  No wat**e**r, **e**arth, or ston**e**.
>
>  No riddl**e** ever spoke or read,
>  My binding spell escapes,
>  Darkn**e**ss has never conquered me,

But then there's this line:

> Though light escapes my fate.

and light, indeed, is free from that particular influence. The final stanza begins

> I appear in the fire’s flam**e**s,
>  In the dragon’s d**e**n I live,

and the acclaimed man would then be

> either [John Napier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier) or [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler)

because

> [$e$, the base of the natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), is usually called either "Euler's number" or "Napier's constant".